# Get next available IIS Binding using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7, octopus-deploy

I've been tasked with automating our IIS setups/installations using Octopus Deploy.

Run into an issue where I need to setup the binding, and I have a separate step for each site.

Let's say there's 5 sites.
Currently, we start from every 10th number, but after 600.
So for example, it's a brand new server, we'd start with binding 600, then 601.
When we need to setup a second environment, we would start from 610.

I have the option to run a Powershell script in Octopus Deploy, to be able to pass in a variable.
I figure there's a way of getting powershell to return the binding like so;

Get max ID (to the whole 10'th?) where it's equal or greater to 600.

And then within each step of Octopus Deploy I guess I can increment that value by one, for that project.

Unfortunatley I'm not very familiar with Powershell, if anyone could point in the direction of resources I might need to configure IIS using it, that'd be appreciated.

On a side note, maybe the bindings starting from each 10th isn't the best option, I think it's how we've always done it in case we wanted to expand the sites used, but maybe this is the wrong approach to standardising for us.

Comment: Rather than batching by 10s, what's wrong with just deploying to the "next available" binding?

Comment: I'm not sure there is, it's just how we've always done it.

I could certainly voice changing this.

I suppose the concern is, what if we added a 6th site to our application.

Would it be usual practice to just add that to say port 800, where the others are sitting on maybe port 640-645?

Comment: What I've done in the past is declared a port range (e.g. 600-800). Then my deployment method finds the lowest, un-used port and binds to that.

Comment: Just spoke to the guys who sort've started that standard we had, and actually it's not really a requirement.

If we were to add a 6th site, and it be on a binding with a very different number, it's fine, although it looks messy, no actual problem.

Do you mean using Octopus Deploy, you can specifiy a range? I had no idea if so, that could be very helpful.

Comment: [octopus deploy templates](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/steps/community-step-templates)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how one later knows how to navigate to the site if port is assigned dynamically at the point of deployment?